# MVC5 File Upload and Display

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I am currently having an issue with an MVC application that uploads a image to a file server.

```
 public ActionResult UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase file, string newFileName)
    {

        try
        {
            if (file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(file.InputStream);
                Bitmap final = new Bitmap(bm, 150, 150);
                final.SetResolution(72.0F, 72.0F);

                string _FileName = newFileName + ".jpg";
                string _path = Path.Combine(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["imageDirectory"], _FileName);
                final.Save(_path,System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            }
            ViewBag.Message = "File Uploaded Successfully!!";
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "File upload failed!!";
            return RedirectToAction("Error");
        }
    }
```

So the user chooses a file and uploads it to the to the Windows share.  This code works on my machine using IISExpress and on our Test server.  When deployed to our Production server, it appears to be working in that it redirects to Index but the file never changes on the File Server.

IISExpress, the Test server, and the Production Server all point to the same file directory too.

Another issue I ran into while troubleshooting this is that the image from the file server does not display when using the FQDN of the application.  So http://[appName].[domain].[com] cannot display pictures, but http://[appName] does display the image.  Just another weird issue, that did not show up in testing at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the problem and solution;
If it works on your development system then the problem is that you did not give readwrite access to app_data folder. HttpPostedFileBase always upload file temporarily into App_Store and its from there that your Save() method takes the file from. If you don't have App_Data folder, create it. You must give full ReadWrite access to IIS_USERS on your server